# How to move the product price above the product title on a single product page WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to move the product price to appear above the title on a single product page.

I tried this snippet:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 1 );
```

and it didn't work.
Also, the remove_action didn't remove the price from the default position.
Instead, the add_action made a double of the price appear after the add to cart button.

Comment: try to add custom Action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_price_above_title', 1 );
custom_price_above_title() {
    global $product;
    echo '<p class="price">' . $product->get_price_html() . '</p>';
}

Comment: If it doesn't work it is because your theme is already making some customizations, so you need to check, search or ask in your theme support pages.